# Is imageStore atomic?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, compute-shader

When using imageStore in OpenGL, is it atomic?

Or in other words, Assume I have one compute shader invocation that writes "82" to a location, and another invocation that writes "42" to the same location.

When I have a third invocation that reads from the same location: **Am I guaranteed to get the initial value or 42 or 82? Or can I get an undefined value because they could both write at the same time?** (I know its not sure which one I will get).

**Would the answer to above questions change if they both write the same value, instead of different values?**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "shader invocation"? Is this a single draw command with multiple fragments? Multiple primitives? Multiple draw commands? A compute shader being called once, or multiple times?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: The term "[shader invocation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader#Execution_and_invocations)" has a well-established definition.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see, thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, with "shader invocation" I mean "one thread of the same compute shader dispatch"

Comment: It depends on the architecture. Generally imageStore is not atomic, but for small texel sizes (<4 byte) it should be atomic on every hardware. So you won't read 2 byte from one store and 2 byte from another store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification is kinda unclear on this.

The specification talks a lot about the ordering of invocations, as well as visibility of store operations. But at no point does it say what happens if you have two invocations that race on a write to the same memory location. It does not say that the value will be undefined, or that it would be one of several possibilities.

The specification seems to have a hole in it in this regard. As such, I would not do anything that would assume that such writes are genuinely "atomic" in this regard.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks a lot! Why do you think I'm doing something wrong? I think a valid use case could be something along the lines: Check if there is a black pixel in the whole image. To do this, create one compute thread per pixel, load the value, and write to a single shared location (buffer or texture or something) "true" if it is black. That way, it doesn't matter for me what the order of the writes is, I just need to know if at least one of the threads wrote true to that location... And I thought using atomics for that is not very efficient and might be overkill.